# Reloading a JSONP request with different params in sencha touch

Tags: json, sencha-touch, jsonp

I have taken code from GeoTweets tutorial from Sencha Touch learning center and it's working great. I got to a point where I want a form with a Submit button which sends new request to the JSON server with changed parameters. Can anyone please guide me towards the right direction, searched for a bit on google but couldn't find anything that works with Sencha Touch.

Here is the code for the request I am making:

```
Ext.util.JSONP.request({
            url: 'http://myserver/testdetails.php',
            callbackKey: 'callback',
            params: {
                q: "bored",
                rpp: 30,
                uniqueify: Math.random()
            },
            callback: function(data) {
            console.log(data.results);
                var tweet_list = data;
                timeline.update(tweet_list);    // Update the tweets in timeline
            }
        });
    };
```

All I want to do is reload the JSONP with new parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just have

```
var config = {
        url: 'http://myserver/testdetails.php',
        callbackKey: 'callback',
        params: {
            q: "bored",
            rpp: 30,
            uniqueify: Math.random()
        },
        callback: function(data) {
        console.log(data.results);
            var tweet_list = data;
            timeline.update(tweet_list);    // Update the tweets in timeline
        }
    }
```

and then change the params like this

```
config.params = {q:"amused", rpp:20, uniqueify: Math.random()};
```

Then make the request like this

```
Ext.util.JSONP.request(config);
```